# Find the maximum value of possible of $k$

Tags: inequality

Find the maximum value of $k$ for $(1)$ true with all $a,b,c>0$
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+kbc}{(b+c)^2}\geq \frac{3(k+1)}{4}.$$

Here are what I tried:

Suppose: $a+b+c=3$.

Put: $a=b=t,c=3-2t$ with $t>0$.

Thus:

$$k \leq \frac{t^2+9}{2t^2}$$

It became:

$$k= \frac{1}{2}$$

Is it right? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried substituting $k$ in and calculating? Also, in this case, $t\to 0$ limits to infinity.

Comment: But is $k= \frac{1}{2}$ is the biggest one?

Comment: I have adjusted something, I can find the minimum of the RHS

Comment: Check again, $k \leqslant \frac52$ can be supported...

Comment: Oh, I see thanks thank just let $k \rightarrow \frac{3}{2}$